# Using groups with zoom – issue with transforming accurately

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to customize the [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) example to use groups. I have a working example of my attempt [here](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/495ce58fba4f71e6140207e45a428411)

The red circles are just shapes. Each green rect is a group with a rect shape within it. I am struggling to figure out how to translate these groups. As the image shows, the translation of the `green rect groups` is not accurate.

I've been searching around for examples, etc. but haven't found any. This is no doubt pretty simple. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The zoom code I am using is below (and working example is [here](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/495ce58fba4f71e6140207e45a428411) )

```
function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);

  // GREEN RECT GROUPS
  var boxGroups = focus.selectAll("g.box-group")
         .attr("transform",function(d,i){
              return  "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + 0 + ")"
         });

  // RED CIRCLES
  focus.selectAll("circle.circus").attr("cx", function (d, i) { return x(d.date); })

 // other code from original example deleted for clarity       
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially position your `rects`, you do so by setting the `x` and `y` properties of the rect itself.  When you update, though, you are translating the rects parent `g` (and still leaving the `x` position on the rect).  This produces a "doubling" of the position.  Really, I can't understand why you wrap each rect in it's own `g`, remove that and just continue to position them by the `x` attribute.

Here's an updated [block](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/4acfa825b385d9c193819ce7ab48a45b).

BTW, you'll also need to apply the `clip-path: url(#clip);` to your circles and rects to keep them from bleeding into the axis of the plot.

Comment: Thanks! Makes complete sense.

Comment: Oh – quick follow up: I'm wrapping the rect in a group because eventually I want to have an event element consisting of rect, text, and image icon. I'd rather just position a group – not have to dig in and position each item.

Comment: @NoGrabbing, that makes sense and if that is the case, don't set the `x` property of the `rect` and just set the `transform` of the `g`.